# Magento database error code: #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: php, magento, mysql-error-1452

I have downloaded sql file from live Magento site and trying to uploaded on localhost using XAMPP. I'm getting this error code:

> #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (magento2-test.#sql-1c14_33, CONSTRAINT FK_MAG_CAT_EAV_ATTR_ATTR_ID_MAG_EAV_ATTR_ATTR_ID FOREIGN KEY (attribute_id) REFERENCES mag_eav_attribute (attribute_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON

[image: screenshot]

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Looks like `mag_eav_attribute` doesn't contain a value for the `attribute_id` you try to insert.

Comment: I opened the magento_eav_attribute table and it does have values for attribute_id

Comment: That's good, but the data must be in the table `mag_eav_attribute`, not `magento_eav_attribute`! Also, can you pinpoint the error on a single INSERT or UPDATE statement? This would make the debugging much easier. And you can also have a look at the other questions (and their answers) with the tag `mysql-error-1452`. Simply click on the tag below your question.